# How to filter data in AngularJS with a min and max?

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have the following data:

```
$scope.events = [{
    "date": "2015-01-01",
    "name": "party"
}, {
    "date": "2015-02-01",
    "name": "birthday"
}, {
    "date": "2015-03-01",
    "name": "graduation"
}, {
    "date": "2015-04-01",
    "name": "wedding"
}];
```

And the user can select a date-range, such as:

```
$scope.dateRange = [
    "start": "2015-01-01",
    "end": "2015-03-01"
];
```

In which case I only want to show the data that is comprised between the dates selected by the user, such as:

```
 $scope.selectedEvents = [{
    "date": "2015-01-01",
    "name": "party"
}, {
    "date": "2015-02-01",
    "name": "birthday"
}, {
    "date": "2015-03-01",
    "name": "graduation"
}];
```

In this scenario, the user has selected a date-range that contains data, but if the user selects a date-range that goes beyond the available data, such as:

```
$scope.dateRange = [
    "start": "2014-12-01",
    "end": "2015-08-01"
];
```

Then I want to return the following:

```
$scope.events = [{
    "date": "2014-12-01",
    "name": ""
}, {
    "date": "2015-01-01",
    "name": "party"
}, {
    "date": "2015-02-01",
    "name": "birthday"
}, {
    "date": "2015-03-01",
    "name": "graduation"
}, {
    "date": "2015-04-01",
    "name": "wedding"
}, {
    "date": "2015-05-01",
    "name": ""
}, {
    "date": "2015-06-01",
    "name": ""
}, {
    "date": "2015-07-01",
    "name": ""
}, {
    "date": "2015-08-01",
    "name": ""
}];
```

Comment: It could be simplified if the date properties are date rather than string.
You can use, library like underscore and use the function _.filter to achieve what you want with some conditional logic for adding the data for missing month.

Comment: @Anand neither of those issues require additional libraries and are both pretty trivial

Comment: I can get the date in a different format if needed. I'm looking for the logic.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly what you want is to create additional nameless events if there's no data for that period?

Comment: yes true. You do not need any library. can be done with native code.

Answer (score 3):

Following should get you started .. variables changed to non scope ones for simple js testing

```
var dateRange = {
    "start": "2015-04-01",
    "end": "2015-07-01"
};

var startDate = new Date(dateRange.start),
    endDate = new Date(dateRange.end);

var res = events.filter(function(item){
    var date = new Date(item.date);
    return date >= startDate && date <=endDate;
});
```

If you want to extrapolate dates, sort the defualt data by date and check first and last values. Then create a loop to push additional items to main array before filtering

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d87c0hcy/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

using underscore. Also add logic if the date range exceeds add the missing values with blank names

```
var events = [{
    "date": new Date("2015-01-01"),
    "name": "party"
}, {
    "date": new Date("2015-02-01"),
    "name": "birthday"
}, {
    "date": new Date("2015-03-01"),
    "name": "graduation"
}, {
    "date": new Date("2015-04-01"),
    "name": "wedding"
}];

//console.log(events);

var startDate = new Date("2015-01-01");
var endDate = new Date("2015-03-01");

var filteredDate = _.chain(events)
                        .filter(function(event){return event.date.getTime() >= startDate.getTime();})
                        .filter(function(event){return event.date.getTime() <= endDate.getTime();})
                        .value();


console.log(filteredDate);
```

<kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gzwgdh19/)</kbd>

Comment: library code is longer and more involved than just using native code in this case. Where's the value added?

Comment: may be you are right when you see it in the context of this problem. In my experience, when ever I set up a new angular js project, I will use either low dash or underscore for simple filtering, sorting, projection. So yes you are right, if you just concentrate on this problem, You do not need any other libarary. You can do it with native code.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d87c0hcy/) of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31656500/2025390) answer to add the code necessary to add the empty events when your range goes beyond available data.

Here's the code :

```
var events=[{
    "date": "2015-01-01",
    "name": "party"
}, {
    "date": "2015-02-01",
    "name": "birthday"
}, {
    "date": "2015-03-01",
    "name": "graduation"
}, {
    "date": "2015-04-01",
    "name": "wedding"
}];

var dateRange = {
    "start": "2014-11-01",
    "end": "2016-01-01"
};

var startDate = new Date(dateRange.start),
    endDate = new Date(dateRange.end);

var eventsOfRange = [];
var curDate = new Date(startDate);
while(curDate <= endDate) {
    // we'll add the correct name for the dates that have an event later
    eventsOfRange.push({
        date: curDate.toISOString().substring(0, 10),
        name: ""
    });
    curDate.setUTCMonth(curDate.getUTCMonth()+1);
}


var filteredEvents = events.filter(function(item){
    var date = new Date(item.date);
    return date >= startDate && date <= endDate;
});

function find(eventsArray, date) {
    return eventsArray.reduce(function(indexFound, curEvent, index) {
        if(date === curEvent.date && indexFound === -1) {            
             return index;   
        }
        return indexFound;
    }, -1);
}

filteredEvents.forEach(function(event) {
    var index = find(eventsOfRange, event.date);
    eventsOfRange[index].name = event.name;
});

document.getElementById('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(eventsOfRange, null, ' ')
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d87c0hcy/3/)</kbd>